# Noninverting amplifier; Saturation point?

Tags: operational-amplifier, amplifier

I had to design a noninverting amplifier with a gain of 5. I used resistances; R1= 1k R2=4K. Then it asked as magnitude is increased what value of input voltage will it begin to saturate?
Drawing of the amplifier I am using
[image: amplifier]

Comment: what have you done to find out? What information do you think is missing here?

Comment: What is the "it" that asked? The amplifier asked you a question? Or is this a homework problem?

Answer (score 0):

"Saturation" is defined to be the points at which the output voltage of the opamp approaches its limits. Those limits are a function of the opamp's internal design and the voltages on its supply rails, and this information can be found in the opamp's datasheet.

Is this enough of a hint to get you going?